# CPU, Disk and Memory Usage of Process Per User

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I've been scouring the net for a answer to my problem, but I can only find some partial solutions.

Basically, I want to end up with a text, csv, etc. file that contains the cpu, disk i/o and memory usage (maybe even network) of processes per user. There are plenty of results for getting the usage per process using PowerShell, but I want to go deeper and see it per user as well.

Windows Task Manager (in 8 and 10 at least) shows this information pretty much exactly as I need it under the "*Users*" tab.

Can anyone help in getting me started scripting this in PowerShell perhaps?

Comment: you can use the same methods to get the memory/cpu usage just filter it by user, for example `win32_process` and `GetOwner()` Method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code which i am using. When i run this script after a minute or two It returns an error which says $.GetOwner() can not be found and in another line it gives me the user name which utilizing the memory more than the others but the calculation is not correct when i compare it with TaskManager user's tab.

```
$h = @{}
get-wmiobject win32_process | foreach { 
    $u = $_.getowner().user;
    if ( $u -ne $null)
    {
        if ( !$h.ContainsKey($u)  )
        {
            $h.add( $u, $_.WS);
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $h.item($u) = $h.item($u) + $_.WS;
        } 
    }
}  
$h.GetEnumerator() | sort value -desc
```